# SQL query to get the result of sum travelled on date and target 5000 (rolling subtraction should get subtracted everyday date in ordered date)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, window-functions

I am new to SQL or MySQL so could anyone suggest me how to get the required result

| Date | travelled |
| --- | --- |
| 22-2-2011 | 100km |
| 22-2-2011 | 200km |
| 30-2-2011 | 200km |
| 23-2-2011 | 600km |
| 23-2-2011 | 200km |

My SQL query:

```sql
SELECT target - SUM(km) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY date;
```

I am trying to get the result.

That the given target is 5000 and i should add each day data and subtract it by 5000 and next day the remaining target will be deleted by sum.

If I enter 22-02-2022

Output: 300 (ie is sum) and 4700 (ie 5000-sum of travelled km)

And next time if I enter the next date ie 23-02-2022

Output: 800 (ie is sum) and 3900 (ie 4700-sum of travelled km)

Comment: I've removed the tag spam here. Please ensure you only tag the technologies you are *actually* asking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by Date to get each day's total and with `SUM()` window function get the running total and subtract it from the target:

```
SELECT Date, 
       SUM(SUM(travelled)) OVER (ORDER BY Date) total,
       5000 - SUM(SUM(travelled)) OVER (ORDER BY Date) remaining
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd13145ee2fadb652beeb61e537d478e).

Comment: Thanks , but i have 1 doubt if i give 1date as input how can I get only that date result should I use limit 1

Comment: @Arya check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fa0e635cd4b758b475e7e3c664b6fac